# How to change upper case to lower case using find and awk and regular expressions

Tags: regex, awk, find

I need to change all filenames in given folder. If there's an uppercase it need to be changed to _lowercase but the first one is always lowercase. Example:
`/folder/FileNameOneTwo.txt -> /folder/file_name_one_two.txt`

There is no need to save the filenames, only to print to the console.
The code:

```
find $1 -type f -print | awk '
BEGIN {
FS = "/"; } 
{ 
split($NF,nazwa,".");
}
{
if(nazwa[1] ~ /([[:upper:]])[[:alnum:]]*/ ){

gsub(/[A-Z]/,"_&");
sub(/_/,"");
print tolower($nazwa[1])
}
}
'
```

Comment: Just for a start, `awk` has got the function `tolower()`.

Comment: I've just edited my code and now I find those files I want to change names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -1
FileNameOneTwo.txt

$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/[A-Z]/_&/g2;s/.*/\L&/'
file_name_one_two.txt
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:upper:]]/,"_&");sub(/^_/,"");print tolower($0)}'
```

Comment: well, awk is required, you need to use my code in the question, otherwise you won't help me

Comment: I placed your code in my question, and the output for the file RazDwaTrzy.txt is: ./ra_z_d_wa_t_r_z_y._t_x_t

Comment: Then you should update your version of `awk`. Replace `[A-Z]` to with `[[:upper:]]` http://ideone.com/kpLv37

Comment: I don't think it's his awk version that's the issue, it's his locale. Some locales have letter ordering like `aAbBcC...zZ` so `[A-Z]` would match every letter except `a` which seems to be what he saw in the output he posted in his comment. Using `[[:upper:]]` as suggested solves the problem (that's what character classes are for after all), no need to change awks.